# How can I move an Adobe Prelude CS6 project

Tags: adobe, cs5

I have a Prelude CS6 project that I need to move to a different folder but there seems to be no way to change the file path for the clips.

When I move the project, in logging mode I see the clips in the project but they have the old file path and I can't see any way to change this. When I double click on a clip I get the error. `The media you are attempting to work on is offline. Please locate your media, bring it online and try it again`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do this 10 minutes later and I thought I'd share it in case it helps someone.

There might be a "proper" way to do this within the program, but this way has just worked for me. The Prelude project file is just an XML document so easy to edit and this method should be bulletproof ( make a copy of the project file first though )

1. Close Prelude
2. Open the Prelude project file in a text editor, eg notepad but you'll need [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) unless you want it to take ages or if it's a very small project
3. Replace all the FilePaths with the new file path ( if you use sublime then it's easy to use ctrl-D to multi-select them all in one go but if you're not a Sublime user you'll need to do them one by one - **only change the file paths fo each clip not anything else at all**
4. Save the file and open in prelude

Eg, for each clip you'll have something like

`<MasterClip AssetName="back-head" AssetType="AssetTypeMasterClip" ClassID="9091c12c-9d39-43b7-b55e-4de81592552c" CreatedDate="11/27/15, 12:54:25" DropFrame="false" Duration="2542700160000" FilePath="C:\old\path\tozfootage\DSCF4661.MOV" FrameRate="8475667200" ImportDate="2015-12-18 03:04:59" ParentClassID="18e728c6-1583-44f4-96da-2a830cded31a" StartTime="0"/>`

change the part where it says FilePath="C:\old\path\tozfootage\DSCF4661.MOV" to your **new\path\to\footage**

- `so you'll end up with FilePath="C:\new\path\tozfootage\DSCF4661.MOV"` - and so on for the other clips
- in my windows 7 machine I can find the path easily by right clicking the address bar in explorer and selecting "copy address as text"

Answer (score 0):

Page 17 of the [Adobe Prelude manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/prelude_reference.pdf) has the answer:

> When you open a project containing files that have moved since you last opened the project, a list of such files is
>   displayed. Click Yes to relink the files by specifying their current location. If you choose to not relink the files, you can
>   manually relink the files later.
>
> 1 In the Project panel, right-click the file with the offline icon , and select Relink. To select multiple files that exist
>   at the same location, use Ctrl-click/Cmd-click or Shift-click.
>
> 2 Navigate to the folder containing the files and select a file. Prelude uses this location to relink all the other files in
>   your selection.
>
> 3 Click Open.

Comment: Yes - no such dialog that I either encountered or was able to find on Prelude however

Comment: I updated my answer with The Answer.

Comment: Yes I would have expected something like that but it wasn't my experience - right clicking on the files did nothing  - I spent ages going through all the menus etc and trying everything I'd do if it were moving eg and AE or PP project - but there was just the error I mentioned . Though I have another project to move and I'll double check when I move that.